# Elasticsearch issue: not working in command line

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run Elasticsearch command line in windows. so for this i download last version `5.2.2` and unzip in `c:` now when i type in command line `elasticsearch.bat` displayed many exception. of course i set `JAVA_HOME`.

**It display below out put.**

```
ntext.java:530)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
258)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:299)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
22)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)

        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)


2017-07-13 22:45:46,571 main ERROR Unable to create file C:\Program Files\elasti
csearch-5.2.2\logs\elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log java.io.IOException:
 The system cannot find the path specified
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$Rol
lingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:463)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$Rol
lingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:445)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(Abs
tractManager.java:112)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager
(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.get
FileManager(RollingFileManager.java:128)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.bu
ild(RollingFileAppender.java:135)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.bu
ild(RollingFileAppender.java:58)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build
(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPlug
inObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:882)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:874)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigur
e(AbstractConfiguration.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize
(AbstractConfiguration.java:227)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(Abst
ractConfiguration.java:239)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerCo
ntext.java:530)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
258)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:299)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
22)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)

        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)


2017-07-13 22:45:46,577 main ERROR Unable to inject fields into builder class fo
r plugin type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender,
element RollingFile. java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache
.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactor
y@1afd44cb] unable to create manager for [C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-5.2.2\l
ogs\elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4
j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@32eff876[pattern=C:\Progr
am Files\elasticsearch-5.2.2\logs\elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog-%d{yyyy-M
M-dd}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTrigge
ringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1,
 modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7), advertiseURI=
null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %marker%.-10000m%n]]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(Abs
tractManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager
(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.get
FileManager(RollingFileManager.java:128)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.bu
ild(RollingFileAppender.java:135)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.bu
ild(RollingFileAppender.java:58)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build
(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPlug
inObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:882)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:874)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigur
e(AbstractConfiguration.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize
(AbstractConfiguration.java:227)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(Abst
ractConfiguration.java:239)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerCo
ntext.java:530)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
258)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:299)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
22)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)

        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)


2017-07-13 22:45:46,584 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class clas
s org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element Rolling
File. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apa
che.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findF
actoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:224)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build
(PluginBuilder.java:130)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPlug
inObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:882)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConf
iguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:874)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigur
e(AbstractConfiguration.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize
(AbstractConfiguration.java:227)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(Abst
ractConfiguration.java:239)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerCo
ntext.java:530)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
258)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:299)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
22)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)

        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)


2017-07-13 22:45:46,591 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appen
ders.
2017-07-13 22:45:46,592 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appen
ders.
2017-07-13 22:45:46,592 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appen
ders.
2017-07-13 22:45:46,593 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appen
ders.
2017-07-13 22:45:46,593 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logge
r config "root"
2017-07-13 22:45:46,593 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_indexing_slo
wlog_rolling" for logger config "index.indexing.slowlog.index"
2017-07-13 22:45:46,594 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_search_slowl
og_rolling" for logger config "index.search.slowlog"
2017-07-13 22:45:46,594 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "deprecation_rollin
g" for logger config "org.elasticsearch.deprecation"
2017-07-13 22:45:46,597 main ERROR Could not register mbeans java.security.Acces
sControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission" "regis
ter")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:457)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:585)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.checkMBeanTrust
Permission(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1848)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(D
efaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:322)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.j
ava:522)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.register(Server.java:389)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfi
gure(Server.java:167)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfi
gure(Server.java:140)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerCo
ntext.java:541)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
258)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigu
rator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:299)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
22)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)

        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)


[2017-07-13T22:45:47,056][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] []
 uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: U
nable to access 'path.scripts' (C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-5.2.2\config\scri
pts)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:125
) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
112) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
22) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5
.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)
 ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)
 ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.scripts' (C:\
Program Files\elasticsearch-5.2.2\config\scripts)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:379) ~[ela
sticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java
:251) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:
215) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:121) ~[e
lasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:236) ~[ela
sticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elas
ticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-5
.2.2\config\scripts
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.j
ava:83) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.jav
a:97) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.jav
a:102) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSyste
mProvider.java:496) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:778) ~[?:1.8
.0_11]
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:764) ~[?:1.8.0_11]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.j
ava:421) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:377) ~[ela
sticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java
:251) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:
215) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:121) ~[e
lasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:236) ~[ela
sticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elas
ticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121
) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Question is why not working?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? Can you copy and paste it instead of putting a screenshot?

Comment: No, this part of that. it is so much.

Comment: @asettouf I put all stack trace.

Comment: I'd suggest you solve the first issue then: `ERROR Unable to create file C:\Program Files\elasti
csearch-5.2.2\logs\elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.` Does your user has permission to write there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with changing the place of `elasticsearch` . Before i put it in drive `C` now i put it in other drive. now it works correctly.
Thanks all for attention.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Please mark it as the answer to the question, to keep the focus on unanswered question.

Comment: @asettouf, Thanks